# Suggestions for Website Maintenance

Tags: web-hosting

I have a website that is being hosted and supported by a company that is going out of business.  We are looking for a company to do maintenance on the code/content side, and will likely move the hosting to Rackspace.com (or another SAS70 certified provider).

We are bringing the CMS with us, which I know is unusual, but we like it and would like to keep it.  What companies should I look at for just CODE and CONTENT maintenance?  It's a PHP/MySQL website.

Comment: Actually, this applies to a broad audience, as the current situation happens a lot more than one would think.  When one custom web designer closes their doors and stops offering support for the site they designed and coded, the customers find themselves in a pickle of a situation.

Comment: Why is this getting voted down 5 years after it was asked?

Answer (score 2):

Is the CMS an open source project?  If so I would recommend getting in touch with a independent consultant (if support services are not provided by the project maintainers themselves) that specializes in that CMS.  You should be able to locate several by participating in the community forums of this project.

If it's a custom/homegrown one, you may want to re-evaluate your needs and find a good, quality open source CMS to migrate to vs. maintaining custom code bases.  In my experience, the latter is more expensive to maintain than the former as you'd need to find a Web development shop or freelancer who's a) good enough to take on somebody else's code and not make a mess out of it (and not want to just write their own thing anyways) or b) hire somebody in-house to maintain it, which may actually end up being cheaper depending what needs to be done today and in the future.